# Generate descriptions in OpenAPI docs using Google Cloud Endpoints Framework

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm building an API using Google Cloud Endpoints Framework v2 on Python App Engine Standard.

Using Endpoints Framework means you can automatically generate OpenAPI / Swagger documentation directly from the code.

However I am unable to work out how to generate *descriptions* for each of the *parameters* (each field in a message) in the API directly from the code.

It's possible to generate a description for the entire API but not for each individual *parameter*.

Using Cloud Endpoints Framework Echo as an example:

```
"""This is a sample Hello World API implemented using Google Cloud
Endpoints."""

# [START imports]
import endpoints
from protorpc import message_types
from protorpc import messages
from protorpc import remote
# [END imports]


# [START messages]
class EchoRequest(messages.Message):
    content = messages.StringField(1)


class EchoResponse(messages.Message):
    """A proto Message that contains a simple string field."""
    content = messages.StringField(1)


ECHO_RESOURCE = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
    EchoRequest,
    n=messages.IntegerField(2, default=1))
# [END messages]


# [START echo_api]
@endpoints.api(name='echo', version='v1')
class EchoApi(remote.Service):

    @endpoints.method(
        # This method takes a ResourceContainer defined above.
        ECHO_RESOURCE,
        # This method returns an Echo message.
        EchoResponse,
        path='echo',
        http_method='POST',
        name='echo')
    def echo(self, request):
        output_content = ' '.join([request.content] * request.n)
        return EchoResponse(content=output_content)

    @endpoints.method(
        # This method takes a ResourceContainer defined above.
        ECHO_RESOURCE,
        # This method returns an Echo message.
        EchoResponse,
        path='echo/{n}',
        http_method='POST',
        name='echo_path_parameter')
    def echo_path_parameter(self, request):
        output_content = ' '.join([request.content] * request.n)
        return EchoResponse(content=output_content)

    @endpoints.method(
        # This method takes a ResourceContainer defined above.
        message_types.VoidMessage,
        # This method returns an Echo message.
        EchoResponse,
        path='echo/getApiKey',
        http_method='GET',
        name='echo_api_key')
    def echo_api_key(self, request):
        return EchoResponse(content=request.get_unrecognized_field_info('key'))

    @endpoints.method(
        # This method takes an empty request body.
        message_types.VoidMessage,
        # This method returns an Echo message.
        EchoResponse,
        path='echo/getUserEmail',
        http_method='GET',
        # Require auth tokens to have the following scopes to access this API.
        scopes=[endpoints.EMAIL_SCOPE],
        # OAuth2 audiences allowed in incoming tokens.
        audiences=['your-oauth-client-id.com'])
    def get_user_email(self, request):
        user = endpoints.get_current_user()
        # If there's no user defined, the request was unauthenticated, so we
        # raise 401 Unauthorized.
        if not user:
            raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException
        return EchoResponse(content=user.email())
# [END echo_api]


# [START api_server]
api = endpoints.api_server([EchoApi])
# [END api_server]
```

This is the accompanying swagger documentation that has been generated:

```
{
  "basePath": "/_ah/api",
  "consumes": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "MainEchoRequest": {
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "type": "object"
    },
    "MainEchoResponse": {
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "type": "object"
    }
  },
  "host": "echo-api.endpoints.8085-dot-3333519-dot-5002-dot-devshell.appspot.com",
  "info": {
    "title": "echo",
    "version": "v1"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/echo/v1/echo": {
      "post": {
        "operationId": "EchoApi_echo",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "body",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/MainEchoRequest"
            }
          },
          {
            "default": 1,
            "format": "int64",
            "in": "query",
            "name": "n",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "A successful response",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/MainEchoResponse"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/echo/v1/echo/getApiKey": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "EchoApi_echoApiKey",
        "parameters": [],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "A successful response",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/MainEchoResponse"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/echo/v1/echo/getUserEmail": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "EchoApi_getUserEmail",
        "parameters": [],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "A successful response",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/MainEchoResponse"
            }
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "google_id_token-c0b0c9d9": []
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "/echo/v1/echo/{n}": {
      "post": {
        "operationId": "EchoApi_echoPathParameter",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "body",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/MainEchoRequest"
            }
          },
          {
            "default": 1,
            "format": "int64",
            "in": "path",
            "name": "n",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "A successful response",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/MainEchoResponse"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "produces": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "securityDefinitions": {
    "google_id_token": {
      "authorizationUrl": "",
      "flow": "implicit",
      "type": "oauth2",
      "x-google-issuer": "https://accounts.google.com",
      "x-google-jwks_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs"
    },
    "google_id_token-c0b0c9d9": {
      "authorizationUrl": "",
      "flow": "implicit",
      "type": "oauth2",
      "x-google-audiences": "your-oauth-client-id.com",
      "x-google-issuer": "https://accounts.google.com",
      "x-google-jwks_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs"
    }
  },
  "swagger": "2.0"
}
```

In the example above I'm looking to try and include a description for the *content* field in the *EchoResponse* and *EchoRequest* message types.

This could be done manually by navigating the OpenAPI specification path --> /echo/v1/echo --> parameters and adding in a description key/field there -
but can it be generated through the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Endpoints Frameworks does not currently support this. The alternative you suggested of manually adding the description is the only way right now.